# Call String or Integer from another Function (actionscript 3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, function, variables, integer

I've got different functions in actionscript 3, one function generates random numbers each time there's a button click. But with another button I want to call the random number which is generated at that moment. I have to call the random number from another function then, but these are two different functions so it just considers it as an undefined property.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to describe here. 
Thanks in advanced!

EDIT: a piece of code

I have an

```
var randomnummer1:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) +1;
```

This piece of code is inside the function

```
function bijMuisKnop(e:MouseEvent):void{ 
}
```

At another function I want to call the randomnummer1 at that moment.

```
function welkNummerKnop(e:MouseEvent):void{
NummerOpDatMoment = randomnummer1;
}
```

But I can't call randomnummer1 because it's inside another function. So I get the property undefined error.

Comment: Hi, any code you can post here will clarify the question, it is VERY unclear now

Comment: Do you need the random number that is generated during the click only or is it alright if you generate a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a class level variable (or a global variable)

```
private var randomNumber:Number;
```

then,

```
function bijMuisKnop(e:MouseEvent):void{ 
    var randomnummer1:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) +1;
    randomNumber=randomnummer1; //Assign to global variable
} 

function welkNummerKnop(e:MouseEvent):void{
    NummerOpDatMoment = randomNumber;
}
```

Comment: So what you are doing is this: Click on 1 button generates a random number. Clicking on another button runs welkNummerKnop. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I click on a button and every time I click, the generated number changes.  But when I click on welkNummerKnop, it displays your current number on another dynamic textfield.

Comment: This would be the way to do it then. If `NummerOpDatMoment` is the name of the text field then you need to do `NummerOpDatMoment.text`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than declaring the variable for the random number inside the handler function you should declare it once outside, so that the variable scope is available to both functions:

```
var randomnummer1:Number;

function bijMuisKnop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    randomnummer1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) +1;
} 

function welkNummerKnop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    NummerOpDatMoment = randomnummer1;
}
```

Comment: This also returns nothing, because every time I hit the button, the number changes.